# The plugin firebase_database requires a higher Android SDK version

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I got this error when i connect my flutter app with firebase rtdb

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:firebase_database] C:\wmsflutter\warehouse_management_system\build\firebase_database\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
> Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
> or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
> or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.database" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

But the problem is thatmy minsdk version is already 19 , i changed it in build.gradle script.

**compileSdkVersion 21

```
defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21
}

compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
```

**

Do you have any idea for this issue ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: targetSdkVersion 21?? why so low ??

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading `minSdkVersion` to 21. And also upgrade `targetSdkVersion` to any versions above 30. Target sdk version 21 is too low for new versions .

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 30
```

Comment: I've tried but no solution :(

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your minSdkVersion 21 and targetSdkVersion 33
For most of flutter libraries target sdk requires 21 or more.

Comment: I've tried but still get the same error.